# Facebook Graph API put Like issue.?

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using Facebook Graph API and I wanted to put Like of any comment so I am doing like this.

```
FacebookGraphAPI obj = new FacebookGraphAPI(AccessToken);
obj.PutLike(item["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", ""));
```

It is not working even it will not give me error so how I can put the like.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the API?

Comment: yes my Runtime version is v2.0.50727 and version is 1.0.0.0

Comment: Can you suggest me which one is latest for C#

Comment: That's an old version. They're up in the 5.x versions now (with a 6.0 alpha).  You really should update it. https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk

Comment: Thanks @DMCS  I have Updated my Library but still I didn't find any commad which is put like can you tell me the command once again thank you for updating..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest API, here's how to do a like (this assumes that there is a graph api like connection on the object being liked)

```
FacebookClient client = new FacebookClient(userAccessToken);
var result = client.Post(item["id"] + "/likes", null);
ProcessResult(result); // your code to determine how to handle the result being sent back from Facebook
```

The above code is from a current production working app of mine.

Happy coding!

Comment: Hi @DMCS I am trying to delete the Like I mean Unlike this like so I will get error like this .(OAuthException) (#100) Can only call this method on valid test users for your app.

Comment: My command like thisk            Facebook.FacebookClient api = new FacebookClient(ExpandingNewsFeedList[0].AccessToken);
            api.Delete(ID);

Comment: Your app is still in sandbox mode and that's why the "Can only call this method on valid test users for your app" error message.  Please ask future questions in a new question rather than in the comments.  Thanks!